# Why do Gaming.SE and Programmers have smaller "about me" sections?

Tags: feature-request, support, design, stack-exchange

Every single SE site (at least, the ones I'm a member on) have their "about me" sections (the box on the right side of your profile's personal info section) at 445 pixel width except for Gaming.SE and Progammers (which have it at 433 and 430 pixels, respectively).

If you want to see for yourself, take a look at my [Stack Overflow profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/814761/purmou) and then my [Gaming.SE profile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/11721/) and my [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/45222/) profile. Those are all images, and altogether they add up to 445 pixels (I did it so that it fit perfectly). I neglected the difference in width between the three sites (and perhaps more).

So, why're they smaller on those sites? I'd like to think that the primary design aspects of each SE site are consistent throughout the network.

I would appreciate the widths of the about me sections of all SE sites to be equal.

**EDIT:** This is also the case with the network profile (the about section there is 380 pixels wide, which is *incredibly* small considering the amount of whitespace on the new network site).

Comment: Note that the Programmers design includes a 5px border around the bio text... I have no idea why gaming would be so small though.

Comment: Do you happen to be a web designer :p ?

Comment: @pleasedeleteme: Why yes, thank you for noticing. :P

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure how this is an interesting questio as the answer is quite lame, but I think there is only one answer possible:

> They have a different *insert anything that is different* because they
>   have a different design/layout. For instance: the buttons (questions, tags, etc) are also
>   differently positioned.

Comment: Sure, but why are most other sites identical in this respect? They have separate designs/layouts, yet their about me sections are the same size.

Comment: The fact that they are identical, means there wasn't a change that made the box of a different size. I mean, it is a fact that the different sites use different designs. Different design can mean some different spacing, border etc etc. This can mean that some elements will be a bit different, I really don't see why this would be unexpected.